# What is the shortcut to move a layer fitting in a transparent canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I open an image, convert the background into a moveable layer. Then I move it around. But how I can quickly move the layer to fit exactly with the canvas?

Thanks for your help.

http://cl.ly/image/3P2k0M1q1C2R/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-04%20at%203.03.24%20PM.png

Comment: You ask about fitting a layer into a document, but looking at your example image, it seems that the document and the layer are both the same size, in which case simply centering the image would work ( or what @theyve is suggesting ). Of course if they are not the same size, it becomes slightly more complicated. --- `Fitting` **or** `Filling` a layer _automatically_ in Photoshop is not the easiest.

Comment: It's the same size, I move the layer around but then I want to get it back to original position. Is there any shortcut for this action. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate *Snap to Document Bounds*.

`View` > `Snap` > `Document Bounds`

Comment: I know it but can I assign a shortcut to this? I do it a lot so I really need a shortcut. Thank you.

Comment: You can make your own shortcuts from any menu element.
`Edit` > `Shortcuts`

Comment: Yes I know I can assign my own shortcut to any menu element but *Snap to Document Bounds* is just a check - uncheck item so I can't assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: It is possible to assign a shortcut to a "check - uncheck" menu item. I just tested it. I think what you really want is a shortcut which directly snaps the current layer to the canvas. I would do this by aligning the layer to the center: `CTRL` + `A` then `Layer` > `Align to Selection` > `Vertical Centers` then `Layer` > `Align to Selection` > `Horizontal Centers`.

Make an Action out of this steps and let it play with a shortcut.

Comment: Exactly. I have an action that does this as well. Action shortcuts require you to use `Function keys`, which is not ideal.  Button mode in the actions  panel can help launching the action too, but it doesn't show folders and it often bothers me. I usually end up getting around this by making a script file (`.jsx`) that launches the action. The file contains only: `doAction ('Name of the action', 'Name of the parent folder for the action');`. Then you can set pretty much any shortcut you want in the `Edit > Shortcuts...` and you can even override default ps shortcuts.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thanks for the solution. I don't think about the Ctrl + A and record it into an action. The only limit is Fn required shortcut. And thanks to Joonas for the script solution. I will try it now.